# glitchy windows 10 loading cursor

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have noticed that whenever the Windows 10 Cursor "Loading" animation triggers, the mouse becomes deformed, and moves up a few pixels from it's original position.

I have only recently purchased this laptop (brand new), however, before I return it, I want to make sure that it's a hardware problem, and not a software one. I have been searching around, but there appear to be no similar cases to mine.

Hopefully, someone can help me identify (or even **fix**) the problem.

Usual cursor: 
[image: Usual Cursor]

Loading cursor:
[image]

Comment: First thing I would try is update your graphics drivers

Comment: No problem. Please mark my answer as accepted so others can see what worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Display bugs like this are usually indicative of a graphics driver issue. Update your graphics drivers and see if that helps.